# imap_msgno() returns 0 for an uid returned form imap_search()

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm not sure how to debug this, the function `imap_msgno()` is returning 0 instead of the message number without any error. This is the part of the code giving the trouble (with debugging info):

```
// Retrieve and order emails
$search = imap_search($this->open, 'SINCE "' . $date . '"');
$sorted_search = $this->order_search($search, $sorted);

// Store all the messages
$Messages = array();
foreach($sorted_search as $msgUID) {
  $msgNo  = imap_msgno ($this->open, $msgUID);
  $header = imap_header($this->open, $msgNo);

  var_dump($msgUID);
  var_dump($msgNo);
  if (empty($header->message_id)) {
    var_dump($header);
    }
  else {
    echo "Good";
    }
  echo " | ";

  // mode code ...
  }
```

This should return many `int (12) int (10) Good | int (11) int (9) Good | ...`. However, that's not the case, it returns this (returns added for clarity):

```
int(12) int(10) Good |
int(11) int(9) Good |
int(10) int(0) bool(false) |
int(9) int(0) bool(false) |
int(8) int(8) Good | 
...
```

As you can see, the `$msgNo` seems to be correct. The [function imap_msgno() in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-msgno.php) doesn't provide any more information about the behaviour of an invalid `$msgNo`, and I'm pieced as it should be a valid `$msgNo` since it's part of the returned `imap_search()`. Any idea of how to debug this or where it's going wrong?

Comment: Are you mixing UIDS and message sequence numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Unless they are being set in the order_search call you are returning message numbers and not unique ids. If you set the option SE_UID in the imap_search call e.g.

```
$search = imap_search($this->open, 'SINCE "' . $date . '"', SE_UID);
```

You should get unique ids.